# How does the dimensions of the Kronecker product work out here?

Tags: linear-algebra

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

If we have linear operators $A,B$ representing linear maps $ S : V → X$ and $T : W → Y,$ then the kronecker product $A \otimes B $ has the property that for basis elements $v_i,w_j$ of $V$ and $W$ respectively then

$$A \otimes B(v_i \otimes w_j) = (Av_i)\otimes(Bw_j)$$

I am confused how the dimensions work out here. Let us limit this to the case where $V = X =W = Y = \mathbb{C}^n$. Then $A \otimes B$ would be a matrix of dimension $\mathbb{C}^{n^2,n^2}$ but wouldn't $v_i \otimes w_j$ be a matrix of dimension $\mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ and you can't multiply these matrices.

Perhaps my definition of tensor product is wrong, for $\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$  I believe the tensor product to be the outer product : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's all a question of indexing. Recall that $\mathbb C^{n,n}$ is just a vector space of dimension $n \cdot n = n^2.$ So $v_i\otimes w_j$ can very well be multiplied with a matrix from $\mathbb C^{n^2,n^2}.$

More technically, it works as follows. Let $B := \{e_j\ |\ 1 \leq j \leq n \}$ be a basis of $\mathbb C^n,$ the *standard* basis, if you want. Then $C:= \{e_j\otimes e_k\ |\ 1 \leq j,k \leq n \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb C.$ Then the general element $x$ of $\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb C$ can be written as $x = \sum_{j,k}\xi_{jk}e_j\otimes e_k,$ so its coefficient vector relative to the basis $C$ is $(\xi_{jk}).$ Note that we have *two* indices, not just one. You can view it as a matrix, as you remarked above.

Now, let $E_{jk} \in \mathbb C^{n,n}$ be the matrix with $1$ at the intersection of the $j$-th row and the $k$-th column and $0$ elsewhere. Then $D:= \{E_{jk}\ |\ 1\leq j,k\leq n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb C^{n,n}.$ As above, $E:= \{E_{jk}\otimes E_{pq}\ |\ 1\leq j,k,p,q\leq n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb C^{n,n}\otimes \mathbb C^{n,n}.$ The general element $M$ of $\mathbb C^{n,n}\otimes \mathbb C^{n,n}$ can be written as $M = \sum_{j,k,p,q}\mu_{jkpq}E_{jk}\otimes E_{pq}$ and has coefficient "matrix" $(\mu_{jkpq}).$ Here we have four indeces instead of the usual two.

With all this notation, the coefficient vector of $Mx$ is
$$
\left(\sum_{k,q}\mu_{jkpq} \xi_{kq}\right)
$$
with free indices $j$ and $p$. This is very similar to the "usual" matrix-vector-multiplication, except that each dimension has a pair of indices, not just one index. However, note the "intertwining" of indices. The indices of $\xi$ are connected to the second and fourth indices of $\mu,$ not the third and fourth.

Finally, let's consider the Kronecker products of $S = (\sigma_{jk}) \in \mathbb C^{n,n},$ $T = (\tau_{pq}) \in \mathbb C^{n,n},$ $x = (\xi_k) \in \mathbb C^n,$ and $y = (\eta_q) \in \mathbb C^n.$ We have
$$
S\otimes T = \left(\sigma_{jk}\tau_{pq}\right) \in \mathbb C^{n,n}\otimes \mathbb C^{n,n}
$$
and
$$
x\otimes y = \left(\xi_k\eta_q\right) \in \mathbb C^n \otimes \mathbb C^n.
$$
From this, we get
$$
\begin{align}
(S\otimes T)(x\otimes y) & = \left(\sum_{k,q}\sigma_{jk}\tau_{pq}\xi_k\eta_q\right) \\
& = \left(\left(\sum_k\sigma_{jk}\xi_k\right)\left(\sum_q\tau_{pq}\eta_q\right)\right) \\
& = (Sx)\otimes(Ty) \in \mathbb C^n \otimes \mathbb C^n.
\end{align}
$$
We find that everything fits nicely together.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your detailed answer. I can't quite get my head round how free variables are working? This is quite abstract to me, I can't help thinking of $\mu_{jkpq}$ as a 4-dimensional array where either elements will be different if free variables $j,p$ are changed, or $\mu_{jkpq}$ can be "flattened" to a 2-dimensional array if the elements don't change with a change of free variables. I'm new to Tensors and the such and I just can't see what rules are "allowed" and why. Perhaps I should do some more background reading. Thanks again

Comment: Tensors are quite similar to matrices - except for more indices. If you can handle matrices, you will get used to tensors, too, sooner or later. If you're looking for literature on tensor products, don't search just for "tensor product", search for "multilinear algebra", too.

Comment: Okay thank you for your suggestion!